# Bug when create new Thread for a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm using this code to constantly accept when a new `Socket` connect to Server:

```
    while (true) {
            Socket socket = null;
            socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("A client is connect...\n");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Thread acceptClient = new Thread(new ClientHandler(socket, in, out));
            acceptClient.start();
        }
```

But when a connection is created, I see this in the console:

> A client is connect...
>   A client is connect...
>   A client is
>   connect...

I don't understand why this line is displayed 3 times. Can anyone explane?

Comment: Do you control the client code?  Some clients, like web browsers will make an OPTIONS connection and/or a GET for a favicon.png before the first GET request. That's just a guess. Either way, it's the client.

Comment: Could please attached client code. Sometimes issue is happens in client side